# Why is blank=True in my model not propagating to my model form?

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I have a model as below:

```
from cities.models import City
    
class Post(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(City, default='', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and in the template:

```
<form id="dropdownForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ wizard.form.media }}
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <div class="content-section-idea-detail-1stpage mt-4 text-center">
        <label for="selectorlocation" class=""><h4><b>Select your location:</b></h4></label><br>
        {{ wizard.form.location }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <input id="id_sub_post_details" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-2"  type="submit" value="{% trans 'submit' %}"/>
</form>
```

But the problem is that, I am not able to leave location field empty as it verifies the field before submit. However, I expect `blank=True` disables the validation. Do you know where is the problem happening?

P.S. The django version is the latest version, > 3

and in forms.py:

```
class post_form(forms.ModelForm):
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=City.objects.none(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
            url='location-autocomplete',
            attrs={
                'data-placeholder': '<span class="fe fe-map-pin"></span> City',
                'data-html': True,
                'style': 'height:55px;width:450px;min-width: 27em !important ;',
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [ 'location']
        search_fields = ['location']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(post_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['location'].queryset = City.objects.all().select_related('region', 'country')
```

Comment: Can you show us your model form and your view?

Comment: I just added form, could it be enough? as it is a wizard form, it's a bit complicated to post a summarised view and its urls

Comment: can you try add `required=False,` inside `forms.ModelChoiceField`, below line `queryset=City.objects.none(),` ?

Comment: @NgocPham Yes true, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have declaratively defined the `location` field in your form, it is no longer using any of the form related attributes you've have set in your model.

Either add a `required=False` to your field in the model form, or you can just use the default formfield implementation from the model and not define the field at all on the form level.